# Android - Default Alert Dialog Button position to the bottom of the Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to control the position of the Button in the default alert dialog?

I am trying to position the button to the bottom of the window.

[image: Alert Dialog Screenshot attached]

Bigger the device, the position of the Button is off from the bottom margin of the Alert dialog.

Tried a couple of different options but it's not working.

I am also not trying to use a custom dialog and just use the default alert dialog box.

Here is my code :

```
 public void showTargetDialog() {

    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);

    numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Set target")
            .setPositiveButton("    SET    ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    int weeklyTarget = numberPicker.getValue() ;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("    CANCEL   ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // No Action Required
                }
            });

    builder.setView(numberPicker);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout( (int)(0.75 * width), (int) (0.52 * height) );

    Button posButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    Button negButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

    // NOT WORKING
    posButton.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsPos = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) posButton.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsPos.weight = 1;
    //NOT WORKING
    layoutParamsPos.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM ;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsNeg = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) negButton.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsNeg.weight = 1;

    posButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsPos);
    negButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsNeg);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you could and should do that. If you really want to, create your layout then create a custom dialog yourself.

Comment: Is there any downside to taking this approach? The main issue seems to be the dialog width, height for different devices wherein depending on the button position, sometimes the buttons don't show up in the default dialog. Trying to understand how that will be solved by custom dialog or will i run into the same issues with the custom dialog as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to set the padding of the buttons:

```
public void showTargetDialog() {

    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);

    numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Set target")
            .setPositiveButton("    SET    ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    int weeklyTarget = numberPicker.getValue() ;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("    CANCEL   ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // No Action Required
                }
            });

    builder.setView(numberPicker);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

    int[] buttons = new int[] {AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL};
    for (int i : buttons) {
        Button b = null;
        try {
            b = dialog.getButton(i);
            b.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Change 0 padding to what you like.

Comment: This solution works. Is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: I have used it and testing it in the genymotion emulators and about 4 devices with different versions of android and it's working.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Accepted as answer.